# Wordpress 5.8 : display new widget

Tags: widgets, templates, block-editor

I've started a new website with the newest **Wordpress 5.8**.

I've made a new **widget** thanks to the new widget builder which use **Gutenberg block**.

In my *functions.php*

```
register_sidebar(
    array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Entête de la page d\'accueil', 'domain' ),
        'id'            => 'head-homepage',
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    )
);
```

The template : *sidebar-head-homepage.php*

If I use this : `<?php get_sidebar('head-homepage');  ?>`, the template is called, but by default it's empty (obvioulsy, cuz the file is empty...) and *$args** is empty

If I use this : `<?php dynamic_sidebar('head-homepage');  ?>`, data from my widget is rendered, but the template is not callded.

So now, how to call my widget correctly, so that I can use variables to add some CSS on it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do none of my widgets have a title?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/395595/why-do-none-of-my-widgets-have-a-title)

Comment: Unfortunatly, I don't think so

Comment: You need to describe your issue more clearly then. What template is not being called?

Comment: (edited my post a little) When my template *sidebar-head-homepage.php* is called by **get_sidebar**, *$args* is empty. If I use **get_sidebar**, *sidebar-head-homepage.php* is not called, but the default rendering is displayed. I'd like to use **get_sidebar** and use *$args* so that I can use CSS inside my template

Comment: Are you saying that `before_widget` etc. aren't being used on the widgets? That's addressed by my answer I flagged at the beginning. When you add blocks to widget areas using the new widget editor these fields are not used.

Comment: So how do I retrived data from the block to display it in my template ?

Comment: You use dynamic_sidebar

Comment: As I said in my OP, I can't access to my template if I use dynamic_sidebar

Comment: I don’t understand what “I can't access to my template” is supposed to mean.

Comment: The template is not called with dynamic_sidebar.

Comment: _What template_???